# Where to place javascript functions in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm somewhat new to wordpress and had created a custom page/template to achieve some basic calculator operations. To do so I have an html form that performs a javascript function on input:

Form:

```
<form oninput="T_Convert()" class="calculator">
        <h6 class="three-col">Temperature to Convert</h6>
        <h6 class="three-col">From</h6>
        <h6 class="three-col">Converted Temperature</h6>

                <input type="number" step="any" id="Temp" name="Temp" class="three-col">
                <select id="conversion_T" name="conversion" class="three-col">
                    <option value="C-F" selected>Celsius to Fahrenheit</option>
                    <option value="F-C">Fahrenheit to Celsius</option>
                </select>
            <p id="temperature" class="three-col"></p>
</form>
```

js function in functions.php:

```
function add_js_functions(){
?>
<script>
    function T_Convert() {
        var num = document.getElementById("Temp").value;
        var convert = document.getElementById("conversion_T").value;
        if(convert == "C-F"){
            num = num*9/5 + 32;
            document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = num.toFixed(2) + " Degrees Fahrenheit";
        }
        else{
            num = (num-32)*5/9
            document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = num.toFixed(2) + " Degrees Fahrenheit";
        }
    }
</script>
}
add_action('wp_head','add_js_functions');
```

I was wondering if it's good practice to keep javascript functions in the functions.php file or whether I should put it in a separate file. If I should make a new file where should I put it in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of a point in adding javascript functions into functions.php unless you will utilize some PHP code within the javascript function or if you need the javascript defined in a specific place in the source code (in that case you might want to use a predefined WP hook). For a pure javascript function, you should ideally be using some kind of Parent / Child theme setup where your parent theme files remain unmodified so that they can be updated without overwriting any changes, but your child theme can take precedence over specific files (such as custom.js or style.css). Every WordPress setup is different so it's hard to advise you without knowing more details.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am actually using a woocommerce theme on my website, but I just wanted to make a custom page that included javascript. I could include these functions on the specific page template however I thought that looked cluttered? Should I create a custom.js then and place it in the js folder? Furthermore is making the file enough or do I need to tell wordpress where to find it?

Comment: If you will only use the calculator function on one page, I don't see anything wrong with slapping into that page's template (that's what they're there for). If you want to make it reusable or extendable in the future, it might make sense to define a [custom hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/) in functions.php and call that hook in the page's template. 
It all depends on you and how sophisticated you want to build your system. Also consider, are you the only one working on the site or will other developers go crazy trying to find the javascript you wrote.